# why e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() don't work?

Tags: jquery

if I click on a link it goes to the link url instead of executing my function instructions

I've already tried some insights here on stackoverflow but nothing, maybe something escapes me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("ok");
    var index = % (this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(url, function(data, status) {
      alert("Status: " + status);
      $('#1').children(':eq(' + index + ')').after(" " + data);
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <a href="prova.htm">link</a>
  <a href="prova.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/index1.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/index2.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/index3.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/index4.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/index5.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/index6.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/index7.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/index8.htm">link</a>
</div>
<div id="2"> <a href="http://www.xyz/page1.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/page2.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/page3.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/page4.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/page5.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/page6.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/page7.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/page8.htm">link</a>
</div>
```

the file is uploaded to a heroku server, it should add the loaded document to the link. In local host it would be enough to alert ok, because even that does not go directly to the link url. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet  where you can see the syntax error you've made.  As such I'm voting to close this question as it's caused by a typo. Also note that jQuery 1.3.2 is massively out of date. You *need* to update it.

Comment: You also *need* to learn to check your browser console window.  I recommend using chrome and installing an extension which pops up when you have a javascript error ("JavaScript Errors Notifier")

Answer (score 1):

Please check you code, you are using `%`, but need to use `$`, works example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("ok");
    var index = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(url, function(data, status) {
      alert("Status: " + status);
      $('#1').children(':eq(' + index + ')').after(" " + data);
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <a href="prova.htm">link</a>
  <a href="prova.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/index1.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/index2.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/index3.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/index4.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/index5.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/index6.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/index7.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/index8.htm">link</a>
</div>
<div id="2"> <a href="http://www.xyz/page1.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/page2.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/page3.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/page4.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/page5.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/page6.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz/page7.htm">link</a>
  <a href="http://www.abc/page8.htm">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions which are basic typos. They don't help any future visitor and just serve to prevent the question being auto-deleted. Just leave a comment on the question to help the OP and vote to close.